Getting output from joined tables with Django
I have the following example tables in MySQL DB being interacted with Django
class Env(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class ExecutionDetail(models.Model):
    executionid= models.ForeignKey(Execution)
    job= models.CharField()

class Execution(models.Model):
    name= models.ForeignKey(Env)
    executionid= models.CharField()
    envname= models.ForeignKey(Env)

I select data using views
def v_job_history(request, job):
        logger.debug("Calling history jobs")
        jobname=job
        myjobs = ExecutionDetail.objects.filter(job=job)
        template = loader.get_template('history_jobs.html')
        context = {
                'myjobs': myjobs,
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

Then in my HTML I try and display my data, e.g.
  {% for x in myjobs %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{ x.execution.envname}} </a></td>
        <td>{{ x.execution.name }} </a></td>
        <td>{{ x.job}}</td>
        </tr>
  {% endfor %}

The problem is x.execution.env_name will return Environment object (2) etc.
I have tried x.execution.env_name - returns objects. x.env.name, x.execution.env.name which return nothing.

x.executionid.envname.name

Thanks your explanation helped greatly and worked.

I would advise to give the ForeignKeys better names, .executionid is not the id of an Execution, it is an Execution object, so:
class Env(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class ExecutionDetail(models.Model):
    execution = models.ForeignKey(Execution, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job = models.CharField()


class Execution(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Env)
    executionid = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    env = models.ForeignKey(Env, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
then you can use:
{% for x in myjobs %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ x.execution.env.name }}</a></td>
    <td>{{ x.execution.name }} </a></td>
    <td>{{ x.job }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
and boost efficiency with:
def v_job_history(request, job):
    logger.debug('Calling history jobs')
    jobname = job
    myjobs = ExecutionDetail.objects.filter(job=job).select_related(
        'execution__env'
    )
    context = {
        'myjobs': myjobs,
    }
    return render(request, 'history_jobs.html', context)
